# Float left elements do not stack

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with some floating elements.
What I want is when you resize the browser window that box 3 is right under box 1

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <p>box 1</p>
    <p>box 1</p>
    <p>box 1</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
     <p>box 2</p>
    <p>box 2</p>
    <p>box 2</p>
    <p>box 2</p>
    <p>box 2</p>
</div>
<div class="box">
     <p>box 3</p>
    <p>box 3</p>
    <p>box 3</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width:80px;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid slateGrey;
    margin:0 0 0 10px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

See Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/He2e7/)

I tried something with the clear property but nothing helps.

Comment: This is reqired behavior.

Comment: When u resize the result window on the Fiddle you see that box 3 is going under box 2, but i want it right under box 1 so that there is no gap under it

Comment: @Joum no i will try that, i will let you know

Comment: @joum nope did nothing

Comment: I didn't quite understand the requirement, thats why my suggestion didn't work... sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this dynamic layout only with js. For example with [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin.

Comment: Okey... yes i know that plugin, but i was wondering if there was a CSS only way. but if there is no other way i use that plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the layout when you resize the browser and hit certain dimensions, you should probably look into media queries.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries

There is a lot of material out there about the subject, so I'm just linking wikipedia for reference.

Comment: all i want is that box 3 is going right under box 1 when there is place for 2 elemets next to each other.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected CSS behavior. If you resize the browser window while you have the fiddle open, box 3 appears under box 1. If you want box 3 to appear like that at all times, you need to add something like this `.clear` class:

```
.clear{
  clear: left;
}
```

You'll notice that box 3 will appear in the correct place, but a bit lower, just under box 2's bottom border. Because all of the boxes are floated, they are treated by CSS as if they were on one line, that line being as tall as the tallest `.box`. When you introduce a box that's `.clear`ed, it will appear under that line. You can adjust the position using `margin-top`, for example change the `<div>` element of box 3 to:

```
<div class="box clear" style="margin-top: -70px;">
```

Hope this helped.

EDIT: Oh, also: if you want this to be dynamically added whenever there's no room to display all three boxes side-by-side, figure out how much space you need for the three boxes to be together on one line and then use a media query, like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px){
    .box.clear{
      clear: left;
      margin-top: -70px;
    }
  }
```

500px being your required space. I would recommend against using this if the contents of your boxes are going to be changed a lot.

Comment: Yes that workt but i got a dynamic page so the content of those boxes can be diferent every time so margin-top:-70px; could be on a later point margin-top:-120px;

Comment: @user1502014 Unfortunately, nothing you can do about it. There probably are ways to figure this out in JS, but remember that there's such a thing as working too hard to reinvent the wheel. The simplest solution would be designing a better layout that expects dynamic content changes.